How can I fix random time offset in Windows Server 2016 without rebooting?
6 of our servers (which unfortunately are lots) changed their OS time at random (different) times by also random and different amounts for each of them. Time as well as date were changed by a maximum of several months (every server stayed within 2024), sometimes to the past, sometimes to the future. The last change as of now happened on 22/08/2024. The BIOS time changed as well.
The time resynced and stayed correct after a server restart every single time. However, we can’t restart every server before or after these incidents happen because every restart means a data loss for us as the servers monitor several peripherals each.  So we’re looking for any kind of solution which doesn’t mean a restart and the resulting data loss for us.
With these restarts came updates. The security updates KB5041576 and KB5041773 got installed as well as the windows update KB5041951. However, I researched those updates and couldn’t find any info regarding time synchronization. We also tried the standard command line prompts and looked into the event logs, as you can see in the picture (I roughly translated it into English).
Every idea is welcome and we’ll try as soon as the next server tries us.
see the event log here

System: Windows Server 2016
Already tried:
date 
time 
w32time /resync

should have set the input as time and date but failed with the message that the time offset was too big and resync couldn't succeed
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time

this one worked, but the server changed its time by itself after 2 minutes (probably because BIOS time was still wrong?)
